# VB .NET - Autosize datagridview row height

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, resize

**Problem Definition**

So I am trying to do something that should be very basic; however, I can't seem to make it actually work.  I am simply trying to make my datagridview autoresize every row height to the text entered.  Am I missing something?

**What I have tried**

I have read through examples on SO and other sites and they all recommend a similar idea. So to make it simple here is *exactly* what I have done so far:

1. I created a new datagridview.
2. I clicked on columns > Add and use the default name and type (textbox)
3. I kept the Autosizemode of that column at None and DefaultCellStyle WrapMode to True.
4. I changed the datagridview's AutoSizeRowsMode = AllCells

From there I build my project and type some data in, but the column simply grows the column width and not the row height:

[image]

Am I missing a step somewhere? I purposely put every step I did because I feel like I am just missing something very simple...

Comment: If the columns are set to be autosized, then they will resize and the wrap/row-height will never be forced to change. The column widths need to be fixed to force lines to wrap and row heights to increase

Comment: @soohoonigan I updated my question by not changing the column resize property on step 3. Then the column stays fixed but the row never resizes. See the updated GIF.

Comment: It will wrap the next word if it goes over the right edge.  Since you only have one word (no space to break it up) it won't wrap.

Comment: @LarsTech Ha simple things... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

go to the data grid view -->properties --> default cell style-change the wrap setting to **true** then use the **autosizerow** property as any mode like allcells or display cellslike